# returning mutated structures efficiently

Tags: memory, lisp, structure, common-lisp

I have a structure:

```
(defstruct spider omegas values continuation)
```

and I have functions that take in this structure and return a mutated version of it:

```
(defun dec (s)
  (make-spider
    :omegas (spider-omegas s)
    :values (cons (- (car (spider-values s)) 1) (cdr (spider-values s)))
    :continuation (cdr (spider-continuation s))))
```

And I have a hunch that this is creating new instances of `spider` in memory that don't need to be there (google has been no help). I care that what I'm returning is its own block of memory but I don't care about the `spider` that is the argument `s` by the time I'm done with the function. Is there a smoother way to return structures like this?

Comment: How do you know it is creating new instances of `spider`?

Comment: I don't. If that could be answered that would also suitably answer the question at hand. I have tried google to no avail. My C brain is convinced they are new copies however

Comment: it is indeed creating a new instance.  In some theoretical sense it might not: if a very heroic compiler could prove that the old instance was unreachable it could, I suppose, reuse the old instance, but that's implausible heroic I think.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you just want to mutate the argument structure object:

```
(defun dec (s)
  (decf (first (spider-values s)))  ; mutates the list of values
  (pop (spider-continuation s))
  s)
```

Comment: Thank you. I was missing the fact that you can write `s` as a statement on its own to return it from the function.

Comment: @Stegosaurus: or less used: `(return-from dec s)`

Comment: @Stegosaurus: *There are no statements*: Lisp is an expression language.  The value of a function is the value of the last expression in its body which in this case is whatever is bound to `s`, which is the structure passed as an argument to the function.